# How to use PullToRefresh without RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I want use **PullToRefresh** but in my application I don't use `recyclerview`, and use this widget : `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`. 
I should set pull to refresh to load new data in my application, how can I it?
Please **don't offer** to me for use `RecyclerView`, because I haven't use `RecyclerView`.
 
I want use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` .

How can I it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

```
this.srl1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.srl);
        if (srl1 != null) {
            srl1.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.red, R.color.green, R.color.blue);
            srl1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    Refresh();
                }
            });
        }
```

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/srl"
    >



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```